# ASP.NET Core MVC - Cookie Middleware w/o Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to modify the default Web Application template to use Cookie Authentication instead of Identity. So here's what I did:

1/ Remove anything involves Identity

2/ Follow this guide https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html

> Problem

When I tried to access restricted resource (**/Home/Secret**), I am redirected to Login page => **correct behavior**.

I enter email/password and submit => cookie named **.AspNet.MyCookieMiddlewareInstance** created in client => **correct behavior**.

BUT then I got redirected to **Account/AccessDenied** instead of **/Home/Secret**. Where does **/Account/AccessDenied** come from?

I could not seem to figure it out. Can you help me out here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. After some research and tweaking it worked ...
Now I think the problem was the following. At first I had the Principal constructed as following

```
 var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(myclaims));
```

but actually it should have been like this

```
 var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(myclaims, "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance"));
```

Now this String "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance" apperently must be set.

Also this would be the full Configuration and Controller:

In Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Auth/Login"),
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Auth/Denied"),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true
        });


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                "default",
                "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

And then in the AuthController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (model.Username == "test" && model.Password == "pass")
        {
            var myclaims = new List<Claim>(new Claim[] { new Claim("Id", "SOME USER ID FROM SOMEWHERE!!") });

            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(myclaims, "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance"));

            HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("MyCookieMiddlewareInstance", claimsPrincipal).Wait();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View(new LoginModel());
    }
```

Hope this helps even if its kinda late.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of the constructor you use to create new ClaimsIdentity instance. If you don't specify authentication type, IsAuthenticated property is set to false, and it causes the error you describe.

[Here is a blog post on this topic](https://leastprivilege.com/2012/09/24/claimsidentity-isauthenticated-and-authenticationtype-in-net-4-5/)

> It is now possible to create a ClaimsIdentity that has claims, but having IsAuthenticated set to false.
> ...
> To have IsAuthenticated set to true, you need to specify an authentication type in the ctor:
>
> `var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, “Custom”);`